# Is it possible to have a wildcard in the middle of a sub/sub-subdomain etc?

Tags: ssl, dns, wildcard-subdomain

If I wanted to have a website domain which reads `at.______.last.com`, where the middle word/domain can change OR not be there at all (e.g. `at.long.last.com`, `at.final.last.com` OR without e.g. `at.last.com`), is this possible or would that require manually making sub domains for every single entry?

Comment: Usually it is not possible, but it depends on your DNS service provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change. With Wildcard SSL you can only change sub domain name.

**Example 1:**

If you have issued Wildcard SSL certificate for *.domainname.com then you can secure:

mail.domainname.com
login.domainname.com

**Example 2:**

If you have issued Wildcard SSL certificate for *.subdomain.domain.com then you can secure:

blog.subdomain.domain.com
signup.subdomain.domain.com

But you can't change the middle of the subdomain name.